# Xcode iOS Simulator Can't See Mass Namebased VirtualHost (localhost)

Tags: xcode, localhost, ios-simulator

The Xcode iOS simulator can see addresses like localhost/phpmyadmin or localhost, but it cannot see domains specified in /etc/hosts like mysite.myname and cannot access my Apache Virtualhosts. Safari just gives a "server not found" error.

Hmm...

Any idea how to fix?

My apache.conf looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName myname
  ServerAlias *.myname

  CustomLog "/Users/myname/Sites/logs/dev-access_log" combinedmassvhost
  ErrorLog "/Users/myname/Sites/logs/dev-error_log"

  VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/myname/www/%0
</VirtualHost>
```

and my etc/hosts looks like this:

```
 127.0.0.1       mysite.myname
```

I access a site by typing http://mysite.myname on my local machine, and it works. And I can even make changes to apache.conf and the simulator sees them. But no access to namebased virtualhosts. Weird.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this?

Comment: This started working at some point with an xcode update. I'm on High Sierra.